# Why doesn't CMake initiate a rebuild when dependent imported library is updated?

Tags: cmake

If we create `libFoo.a` first with `add_library(Foo STATIC foo.cpp foo.h)` and then do

```
add_library(Foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libFoo.a)
add_library(Bar STATIC bar.cpp bar.h)
target_link_libraries(Bar Foo)
```

After `touch libFoo.a` and then `make` there's no rebuild. Why is that?

What happened in my real situation is that after I update one of my third party dependencies  by compiling their source and running `make install`, the build folder in my project that finds the installed third party dependencies via `find_package` does not get rebuild. I had to delete the build folder and compile from scratch to get the proper updates. Is this a bug in CMake?

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right, if Bar is `SHARED` it actually rebuilds. I will have to figure out how to create another minimal example to represent my actual problem, but if you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it since answers the problem of this minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you write

```
target_link_libraries(Bar Foo)
```

there is no **dependency** between `libBar.a` and `libFoo.a`, so modifying the latter doesn't trigger rebuilding the former.

This is because `Bar` is a STATIC library, and creation of a static library doesn't involve linking step.

However, modifying `libFoo.a` would trigger rebuilding a shared library (or executable) which is linked with `Bar` via `target_link_libraries`:

```
add_library(Baz SHARED baz.c)
# That linkage makes libBaz.so to be dependent from libFoo.a
target_link_libraries(Baz Bar)
```

Despite that `Baz` is explicitly linked only with `Bar`, CMake automatically adds `libFoo.a` to be linked libraries of `Baz` and creates appropriate dependency.